# Balanceo de carga entre contenedores docker

Tags: nodejs, docker, aws, nginx

Buen dia, tengo una **API REST en NodeJS** quiero ejecutarla en una instancia AWS de 4 CPU's y 8GB de RAM, para utilizar de forma mas eficiente los 4 nucleos, quiero correr 4 instancias de mi API en la misma instancia AWS.

Estoy aprendiendo **Docker** por lo que me resulto interesante utilizarlo en este proyecto, así que cree una imagen de mi API, ejecute 4 contenedores de la misma imagen y utilice nginx para realizar el balanceo de carga entre los cuatro contenedores.

Utilice el paquete `autocannon` para obtener la cantidad de peticiones que puede resolver mi servidor en X segundos y me sorprendí al ver que el numero de peticiones que resolvía en X segundos había disminuido.

Nginx no esta corriendo en un contenedor, esta instalado en el SO de mi instancia AWS, ¿es esto un problema?
Para acceder con nginx a las API's que corren dentro de los contenedores, simplemente expongo los puertos de mis contenedores al SO "padre", ¿Es esto una buena idea?¿Puede ser responsable de la perdida de rendimiento?

Comment: Sin importar cómo se despliegue cada cosa, eventualmente el throughput va a bajar cuando algún recurso se agote y los procesos (dockerizados o no) comiencen a competir por él. Puede ser la CPU, puede ser el I/O del storage (que por defecto es lento), puede ser la memoria disponible. EN tu pregunta no sabemos si has medido estas variables. Más allá de que uses un nginx o no, instalado de una u otra forma, debes comenzar por determinar cuál recurso se está agotando y, ahí sí, hacer tuning del despliegue. Por ahora, sin datos ni configuraciones, la pregunta es muy amplia

Comment: Gracias @Alfabravo por responder, en caso que sea la RAM el recurso que se este agotando, ¿limitar el uso de recurso para cada contenedor es una posible solución? Buscando un poco mas de info en internet encontré que se recomienda el uso de Docker Swarm para realizar el balanceo entre contenedores ¿es esto cierto?

Comment: La pregunta sigue basada en opiniones. Yo puedo opinar que quitar la capa de abstracción de docker simplifica la cosa. Otro te dirá que levantes contenedores con la misma imagen de forma dinámica usando swarm o alguna otra cosa, de acuerdo a la carga. Y así. Mi recomendación es que definas el problema y lo acotes para poder buscar soluciones que otros hayan usado